# Django ORM migration giving "ValueError: invalid literal for int()" on IntegerField

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm, schema-migration

Step by step, here is how I got to where I am now...

I attempted ran the command `python manage.py migrate` after changing my `Order` table in my database to include include `flowertype = IntegerField()` and was told that I couldn't move forward with the migration until I either **a)** set a default value to the `IntegerField()`, or **b)** let django set it for me. I chose **a** and set the default value to `'something'` just to get the error out of my hair.

Realizing that I shouldn't have put a string into an `IntegerField()`, I have tried the following to fix this issue.

1) tried to reset `models.IntegerField()` to `models.IntegerField(default='1')`

2) tried to reset my sql database using [django-reset](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-reset) and it gave me a ton of errors like `ImportError: cannot import name sql_delete

3) commenting out my `Order` model and then running `makemigrations` & `migrate` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The migration failed in python, so it never made it to the database. You should leave everything as is, and go into the `migrations/` folder and delete the migration which adds the `flowertype` field (it's going to be the most recent one). Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` again, but make sure you have `flowertype = IntegerField(default=1)` (*not* `default='1'`) set in the model definition.

EDIT for further explanation:

When you run the command `makemigrations`, django inspects all of your model definitions in python and compares them against what is in the database. If the two don't match, django will create a migration file which will update the database to reflect the model definitions as they are defined in your python code. This is what the `migrate` command does, it runs all of the new migration files.

So the first time you ran `makemigrations`, a migration file was created which added a column to the `Order` table, and tried to set the value of every row to `'something'`.

This immediately failed, since it was trying to put a `str` into and `int` field.

Since it failed, unless you delete the file, any and everytime you run `migrate`, django was going to keep trying to run that script. There were two options 1) You could've just went in and edited the migration file by hand, or 2) You can just delete that migration file and re-create it once you have your model definitions fixed.

Comment: Yes! You totally helped me out. That did it. I can't give you the credit for the answer for another 8 minutes because SO won't let me, but you got it, friend. Could you please explain to me what deleting that file did? Thanks a million.

Comment: Edited the response with a more in-depth explanation.